# How to modify attributes of Active directory which are not listed in attribute editor?

Tags: attributes, active-directory, schema

Suppose I want to edit the attribute ExtensionName of a user in Active Directory. This attribute is a part of the Object Class top. Also this attribute is listed in the user attributes of the [User-msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#win_2008_r2).

But this aatribute is not listed in the attribute editor tab of the User properties in Active Directory Users and Computers. How to edit such attributes which are not a part of attribute editor?

Answer (score 0):

This attribute should show in ADUC. Verify you don't have "Show only attributes that have values" checked in the filter options.